# Sort Object inside NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an object, as below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CountriesDAO : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * countryname;

@end



#import "CountriesDAO.h"

@implementation CountriesDAO
@synthesize countryname;

@end
```

I have saved this in Array within appDelegate.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *countriesArray;

@synthesize countriesArray;
```

In another controller, I fetch it like

```
  NSArray *countriesArray = appDelegate.countriesArray; It works fine and I get array.
```

As I try to sort it by this way.

```
 NSArray *countriesArray1 = appDelegate.countriesArray;
    NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"countryname" ascending:YES];
    NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];

    countriesArray = [countriesArray1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

I get error

```
[__NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa83b4d0
2013-11-01 13:21:08.882 ECP[13597:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa83b4d0'
```

Here  countriesArray is defined as

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *countriesArray;
```

Comment: Seems like countriesArray is not an array.

Comment: How its not an Array, 

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *countriesArray;

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize the CountriesDAO-objects and put them in the array? This looks correct to me.

Comment: What you are storing into the array countryname or object of class CountriesDAO?

Comment: What makes you think that declaring countriesArray as an NSArray* makes it an NSArray? An object is whatever it is. Just because you assign it to an NSArray* doesn't make it one. And quite obviously, it isn't an NSArray. That's why you get an exception. Look at the code in the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try...

```
[countriesArray1 sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: [Countries compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c63cd0'

Comment: That won't work. His code is correct, it's probably something that went wrong when he puts the objects in the original array

Comment: NSArray *countriesArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *countriesArray1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3",@"2",@"4",@"5",@"1", nil];

    countriesArray = [countriesArray1 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"%@",countriesArray);

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this and it worked for me.

```
countriesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (CountriesDAO *info in appDelegate.countriesArray) {
    [countriesArray addObject:info.countryname];
}    

[countriesArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```c
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [appDelegate.countriesArray mutableCopy];
[sortedArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CountriesDAO *object1, 
                                                     CountriesDAO *object2) {                
    return [object1.countryname caseInsensitiveCompare:object2.countryname];
}];
NSArray *sortedCountriesArray = [sortedArray copy];
```

If something went wrong, check the type of `object1` and `object2`

Answer (score 0):

Its is simple Way to sort array in iOS,it's helps to you

```
[countriesArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [ String_1 compare: String_2];
    }];

// String_1, String_2 are NSString,it's contains in countriesArray
// use  NSMutableArray to rearrange and change values in countriesArray
```

Answer (score -1):

If the array you want to sort contains NSString (which is what I get from your description) you can replace your sorting code with this:

```
sortedArray = [countriesArray1 sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: Countries localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance CRASH ........

Comment: Change `NSArray *countriesArray1 = appDelegate.countriesArray;` with `NSMutableArray *countriesArray1 = [countriesArray1  addObjectsFromArray:appDelegate.countriesArray;`

Comment: The array contains CountriesDAO objects which have a countryname property

Comment: This can't be a way to init NSMutableArray, two time countriesArray1 and what do you want to do by it?

Comment: @Accatyyc, Yes, Array contains object, one more thing also comes in between, thats database,